# Adding ActionListener to a JButton inside JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jeditorpane

In my `JEditorPane` I am loading an html page which has a `JButton` as:

```
<object classid="javax.swing.JButton" value="Button"></object>
```

How can i add an action listener to this JButton ?

Comment: Quick googling gives [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/07/19/embedding-swing-components-jeditorpane) and [this](http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html), both using a similar strategy. There seems to be no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.
first create a Custom Button as shown.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class htmlButton extends JButton
{
     public htmlButton()
     {
          addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
            {
                 System.out.println("HAI");
            }
      });
   }
}
```

HTML part:

```
<html>
<body>
<object classid="htmlButton" value="Button"></object> HAI
</body>
</html>
```

EditorPane Part

```
 JEditorPane pan=new JEditorPane();
 pan.setPage(new java.io.File("a.html").toURL());
```